# Improving an ':has_many :through' association in order to retrieve data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, data-retrieval

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.10 and I would like to improve some code (keep reading for more information) that retrieves data from the database using an `:has_many :through` association.

In the model I have:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :category_relationships

  has_many :categories,
    :through => :category_relationships,
end
```

I would like to improve the following code (that retrieves article categories objects "filtering" some of those by using a `where` statement) so to follow the "Ruby on Rails Way of doing things":

```
@articles.category_relationships.where(:comment_id => @comment.id).map{ |category_relationship| category_relationship.article_category }
```

**How can\should I do that?** Can\Should I "work" on the `@articles.categories` association in order to improve the above code? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use something like below?

```
@articles.categories.where(["category_relationships.comment_id = ?",
                            @comment.id])
```

If you are worrying about DRYness, maybe you could extract the where into the model.

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :category_relationships

   has_many :categories,
      :through => :category_relationships do
     def has_comment(comment_id)
       where(["category_relationships.comment_id = ?", comment_id])
     end
   end

end

@articles.categories.has_comment(@comment.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need nested `has_many :through` relationship between `Article` and `CategoryRelationship`. Here is a plugin that I had once used successfully to achieve exactly what you are looking for.

https://github.com/ianwhite/nested_has_many_through

[This](http://geoff.evason.name/2010/04/23/nested-has_many-through-in-rails-or-how-to-do-a-3-table-join/) blog post also discusses other approaches.

Comment: I "would like"\"prefer" to use build-in Ruby on Rails features.